# Laravel Backpack Upload Field is Not Moving Image to My Path, But it's Storing Path to Database

Tags: image, laravel, upload

When I upload an image using laravel backpack, upload field file path is storing in database, but the image is not moving into folder.

This is my **controller:**

```
$this->crud->addField([   // Upload
    'name' => 'image',
    'label' => 'Image',
    'type' => 'upload',
    'upload' => true,
    'disk' => 'uploads' // if you store files in the /public folder, please ommit this; if you store them in /storage or S3, please specify it;
]);
```

This is my **model:**

```
public function setImageAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "image";
    $disk = "public";
    $destination_path = "/uploads";       
    $this->uploadFileToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
}
```

This is my **config/filesystem.php:**

```
'uploads' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root' => public_path().'/uploads',
                // 'url' => '/photos/',
                // 'visibility' => 'public',
            ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem

ArticleCrudController:

```
...
     $this->crud->addField([ // image
            'label' => "Изображение",
            'name' => "images",
            'type' => 'image',
            'upload' => true,

            'crop' => true, 
            'aspect_ratio' => 1.5, 
            'prefix' => 'vector/upload/' 
        ]);
...
```

model Article
..

```
public function SetImagesAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "images";
    $disk = "uploads";
    $destination_path = "vector/upload/";

    // if the image was erased
    if ($value==null) {
        // delete the image from disk
        \Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->{$attribute_name});

        // set null in the database column
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = null;
    }

    // if a base64 was sent, store it in the db
    if (starts_with($value, 'data:image'))
    {
        // 0. Make the image
        $image = \Image::make($value);
        // 1. Generate a filename.
        $filename = md5($value.time()).'.jpg';
        // 2. Store the image on disk.
        \Storage::disk($disk)->put($destination_path.'/'.$filename, $image->stream());
        // 3. Save the path to the database
        $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = /*$destination_path.'/'.*/$filename;
    }
}
```

..

and add the disk driver in config/filesystems.php

```
'disks' => [

   ...
    'uploads' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' =>public_path(),
             'url' => '/vector/upload',
             'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
...
```

At the end, if you use caching, you must run the command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and look bootstrap\cache\config.php there should be an entry

```
'filesystems' => 
  array (
    'default' => 'local',
    'cloud' => 's3',
    'disks' => 
   ..
      'uploads' => 
      array (
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => 'yorsitename.com\\public',
        'url' => '/vector/upload',
        'visibility' => 'public',
      ),
    ),
```